# Abstract Spring bean not setting property

Tags: java, xml, spring

Having trouble getting a property value set inside an abstract bean and can't for the life of me see how/why. IDE resolves all properties, beans, etc and can see from logs all beans are getting instantiated at runtime.

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class ParentBean<Key extends 
foo { <-- IDE resolves to xml bean definition
...

private boolean mySqlEnabled;

public void setMySqlEnabled(boolean mySqlEnabled) { <-- IDE resolves to xml property value
    this.mySqlEnabled = mySqlEnabled;
}
```

xml context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean name="configurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="localOverride" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:common.data.loader.properties</value> <-- IDE resolves to correct file
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="parentBean" class="path.to.abstract.ParentBean"
      abstract="true">
    <property name="mySqlEnabled" value="${data.loader.mysql.enabled}"/> <-- IDE resolves to correct property value
</bean>
```

The above parent bean is being used in child classes in another module.
Child class xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean name="configurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="localOverride" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:common.data.loader.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/common.platform.stream.provider.xml"/> <-- IDE resolves to above parent xml context

<bean id="childBean"
class="path.to.ChildBean"
      parent="parentBean"/>
```

Despite all efforts and various annotations `mySqlEnabled` property only resolves to default boolean of false, even when data.loader.mysql.enabled is true. What very obvious thing am I missing?

I'm assuming I don't need "configurer" bean in both xmls (probably only parent one), but it didn't work when only in parent context, so I tried putting it in both...

Comment: Is this a session bean? If not, implement Serializable and see if it works.